# Unable to update GlobalValueSet in managed org using jsforce metadata api

Tags: jsforce

I have a managed org where I want to update my 'GlobalValueSet' using jsforce metadata api, but when I try to update I got following error :

> Cannot modify managed object: entity=SharedPicklistDefinition,
>   component=null, state=MANAGED_INSTALLED - picklists

My code is :

```
connection.metadata.update('GlobalValueSet',gValueSet,function(err,res){
   if(err){
         console.error(err)
    } else {
        console.log(res)
    }
});
```

Note : connection and gValueSet is variable that holds connection and GlobalValueSet that is to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is an intentional restriction from Salesforce. You can't manually deploy a Global Picklist that is part of a Managed Package. You have to manually edit it.